# Wordpress migration broken images - even after updating database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, image, migration, permalinks

I was trying to move a Wordpress site from a developing environment (WAMP) to the public domain.

`wampserver 2.5` and `apache 2.4`

My images do have new URL's, according to my database. I tried to update the permalinks as well, after updating my database tables:

`OFFLINE DATABASE`

[image: The offline database]

`ONLINE DATABASE`
[image: The online database]

So, then I tried to update the permalinks as well. Changed them from different options. But I get the following console error:

[image: The console error]

whilst I expected to see the correct image paths.

Then, there are these plugins that change the URL's for you. I tried several plugins, including

`Velvet Blues Update URLs`

[image: Velvet Blues Update URLs Wordpress]

After that, tried the permalinks again, without any success.

Can anyone maybe help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be worth looking at the following plugin:

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

This plugin has been designed to combat the exact problem that you have described above and should resolve all of your content to the correct URLs.

Comment: this didn't solve my problem :-( I have tried the plugin without any result. Migrated the old database to the public domain, converted any url and still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Execute mysql query as follows:

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid,'http://oldsite.com','http://newsite.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid,'http://www.oldsite.com','http://www.newsite.com');

this will replace your old domain with newer one.

Comment: Check if all your files in /wp-content/uploads/ directory are uploaded/moved correctly.
Also check and update permissions for /wp-content/uploads/ directory.

Comment: Thanks @Nishant ! However, I did as you said. All the files are there. Once I login to the back-end and check the 'Media' section, all the media is there with the correct URL's. The update method is executed with full permission. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Ben Did you ever sort this one out? I've seen the same issue lately on a few projects. I think that, in my case, it might have something to do with migrating to a newer version of MySQL (or to a newer version of MariaDB from an older version of MySQL in my particular case).